# F# application Gmail auth issue

Tags: .net-core, f#, gmail, email-client

Update 2021.03.05:
Seems like this doesn't happen with .net 4.8 (application or fsi)
But always happen with .net 5.0 (application and fsi)

https://github.com/ingted/dotnet5mail

It is very weird that if I execute this code with .net4.8, the email would successfully be sent but not with .net 5.0. (It would say "Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.")

1. I already use the app password mentioned here [Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)
2. I only use pure .net library

[image]

Comment: It might help to know what OS, and what version of Fsi.exe.

Comment: Operating system: Windows Server 2019
.NET Runtime: .net 5.0
Editing Tools:
VS 16.9.0 PREVIEW 1.0
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.0.0 for F# 5.0

Comment: Seems like a problem with .net 5.0

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()` is obsolete in .NET 5.

SmtpClient has been obsolete since I believe .NET Core 2.0 and .NET 5 is more closely a progression of .NET Core 3.1, not a progression of .NET Framework 4.8.

> REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0

Microsoft recommends switching to MailKit.

Nuget Link

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/